# Safari extension: communicate between injected script and inserted script element

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I have a Safari extension with an injected script. This injected script creates a SCRIPT element and inserts it into the webpage. The inserted SCRIPT executes fine, however it cannot see the variables and functions in the injected script.

Normally inserted scripts have access to each other's variables, but not in this case. How do I get around this issue so that the inserted SCRIPT can communicate with the injected script?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using window.postMessage to communicate between the Safari-injected script and the inserted script.